# Google home doesn't ask sign in questions. But it works on console.actions testing platform

Tags: java, actions-on-google, google-signin

I'm trying to develop google login intent to identify users. I'm using the default code on developer site https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in

For some reason it works on actions simulator, but not on my home assistant. Shouldn't it work exactly the same on my Google assistant device?

As far as i understand Log in should be triggered by new SignIn() and google handles the confirmation questions. And thats exactly as it works in simulator.

```
//triggered by user
@ForIntent("Start Signin")
public ActionResponse text(ActionRequest request)
{
    ResponseBuilder rb = getResponseBuilder(request);
    return rb.add(new SignIn().setContext("To get your account details")).build();
}

//triggered by login event in dialogflow
@ForIntent("Get Signin")
public ActionResponse getSignInStatus(ActionRequest request)
{
    if (request.isSignInGranted())
    { 
       ...
    }
}
```

On Google assistant device the conversation just stops after asking for login intent. And in simulator i do get the correct google generated sign in questions.

Comment: What do you mean by it just stopping? Do you get a failure from your sign-in check?

Comment: @NickFelker The conversation stops and assistant doesn't say anything. I don't even get the failure.

Comment: Can you see if, on a Google Home, you are a [guest user](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/guest-users)?

Comment: @NickFelker Doesn't seem like it. And i'm able to sign in using the same user from simulator, which makes it really hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like google did something and now everything is working again. I didn't do any changes.